apt-get build-dep for cross-architecture builds?
I am struggling with cross compiling certain packages.
In my environment i do have already the source Debian package including debian/control.
Building nativly for the host architecture (e.g. amd64) works like a charm.
usually apt-get build-dep . will take care of the installation of the build dependencies.
However what's the cross-platform way to install build dependencies?
there is no apt-get build-dep .:arm64 nor any command line argument such as --host-architecture or similar.
Can someone point me how the build environment is commissioned prior
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b --host-arch arm64


Is this wiki page any help?
